# POST request raises AssertionError

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, future

I'm doing a POST request to an API, the code looks like this:

```
@gen.coroutine
def call():
    ...
    response = yield AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(
        HTTPRequest(
            url='https://api.mywebsite.com/v1/users',
            headers=headers,
            method='POST',
            body=json.dumps(body),
            validate_cert=False
        )
    )
    print response, response.body

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(call)
```

The server responds first time with 201 Created and the second time with 200 OK.

But for that code I get this error for the first time. The second time works

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 49, in <module>
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(call)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 389, in run_sync
    return future_cell[0].result()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 129, in result
    raise_exc_info(self.__exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 302, in wrapped
    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 574, in inner
    self.set_result(key, result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 500, in set_result
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 529, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "t.py", line 43, in call
    validate_cert=False
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 520, in run
    next = self.yield_point.get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 409, in get_result
    return self.runner.pop_result(self.key).result()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 131, in result
    return super(TracebackFuture, self).result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 401, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 360, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
AssertionError
```

Comment: Why are you using yield in this call?

Comment: Because AsyncHTTPClient.fetch returns a future

Comment: Could you post more code about the response function? because it seems that the error could come from the yield management...

Comment: Have you initialized your IOLoop?

Comment: Yes it's started. I updated the code

Comment: What version of Tornado are you using? It looks pretty old from the stack trace. Error reporting improved in Tornado 4.0; you shouldn't see a bare AssertionError raised inside concurrent.futures any more.

Comment: It's tornado==3.2; I also tried with tornado==4.1 where I get a Timeout

Comment: But shouldn't you return the value of response to make the function do something? And if it is like that, why don't you just yield the value instead of assigning it to response? Because it seems that when you are executing tornado's function, instead of executing a function it is creating the generator for yield

Comment: So it sounds like the real problem is a timeout, not an AssertionError. Can you restate your question in terms of what happens with a 4.x version of Tornado? (ideally the latest, which is 4.3 instead of 4.1). Otherwise there's not much to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using sync function HTTPRequest in future

```
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient
from tornado.httpclient import HTTPResponse

  def call():
        response = None
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        try:
            body = json.dumps(body)
            response: HTTPResponse = yield http_client.fetch('https://api.mywebsite.com/v1/users', method='POST', body=str(body), headers=headers, request_timeout=5)
        except Exception as e:
            print('get_request error:{0}'.format(e))
```